# Like a family, but maybe bigger

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> They look like a family, but maybe bigger
>   Deadly things this family can trigger
>   Most popular is he who likes to amuse
>   Quite famous with big ears and yellow shoes
>
> Another is rather easy to be adopted
>   Call it smoked pork, to begin with
>   One member doesn't  want anyone to be near
>   You'll get hurt, have fear!
>
> Another member has a special talent
>   Who masterfully creates the base of Holland
>   One is known by a country and another family
>   Though believing them is a real folly
>
> One is a present-long-monosyllabic word
>   One won an imaginary trophy, I've heard
>   So now, to complete the entire quiz
>   Can anyone tell me what this family is?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First I thought it might be

> Disney characters,

but then I turned to the idea of

> fictional mice, or perhaps rodents.

(All of this comes from solving the 3rd and 4th lines, which are the easiest 'in' for this riddle.)

*They look like a family, but maybe bigger*

> Rodentia is an **order**, a bigger taxonomical unit than a family.

*Deadly things this family can trigger*

> The bubonic plague, carried by rats or rather their fleas.

*Most popular is he who likes to amuse

    Quite famous with big ears and yellow shoes*

> This is clearly Mickey **Mouse**.

*Another is rather easy to be adopted

    Call it smoked pork, to begin with*

> Many people have pet **hamsters**, and this word begins with "ham". (Thanks @GarethMcCaughan.)

*One member doesn't want anyone to be near

    You'll get hurt, have fear!*

> **Porcupines**, which are so spiny that nobody can come near them.

*Another member has a special talent

    Who masterfully creates the base of Holland*

> **Beavers**, who create dams, which are common in Holland (thanks @GarethMcCaughan).

*One is known by a country and another family

    Though believing them is a real folly*

> **Guinea pigs** (thanks @GarethMcCaughan).

*One is a present-long-monosyllabic word*

> "Squirrelled" is (at least in some dialects) a long monosyllabic word, and its present tense is **squirrels**.

*One won an imaginary trophy, I've heard*

> This is Beastly **Gerbil**, who won the [Great Puzzling Trophy](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/49170/5373).

*So now, to complete the entire quiz

    Can anyone tell me what this family is?*

> The 'family', or rather order, of rodents.

Comment: Good try, but not the correct answer! By the way, the first and second lines of the last stanza each means something (since each begins with "One"), so that makes 7 mentioned members.

Comment: @WilliamNathanael Darn, I thought I was onto something here. Maybe it's fictional mice then?

Comment: @WilliamNathanael Aha, not necessarily fictional ... edited.

Comment: Yep, correct! I prefer this to Gareth's answer because it's more complete. By the way, 'Squirreled' is a long monosyllabic word, and make it present tense by removing the '-ed'! (Check the link below if you are not sure) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_the_longest_English_words_with_one_syllable

Comment: It's more complete because Rand wrote it after mine and copied the bits of mine he didn't have :-).

Comment: @Gareth Feel free to similarly copy the bits of mine that you didn't get into yours, so that we're both on an equal footing.

Comment: What a waste of effort that would be. Two exactly duplicative answers. You can have the big green checkmark; it's no big deal.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Yeah, it's no big deal for those of you who had lots of reps already. However, it really means something for me, as I want to be an Established User! Care to upvote my question? Hehehe.

Answer (score 5):

I think we are looking at

> rodents.

```
They look like a family, but maybe bigger
Deadly things this family can trigger
```

> Bubonic plague, for instance.

```
Most popular is he who likes to amuse
Quite famous with big ears and yellow shoes
```

> This one might be referring to Mickey Mouse, as Rand suggests, representing mice in general. But there are some other lines that suggest mice; are there other kinds of rodent with prominent ears and yellow feet?

```
Another is rather easy to be adopted
Call it smoked pork, to begin with
```

> **Ham**ster.

```
One member doesn't want anyone to be near
You'll get hurt, have fear!
```

> Puzzled by this. First line seems like mice again, but they don't particularly hurt people and we're clashing with Mickey above.

```
Another member has a special talent
Who masterfully creates the base of Holland
```

> That'll be the beaver, who makes dams.

```
One is known by a country and another family
Though believing them is a real folly
```

> Guinea pig. (They are not pigs, hence the second line.)

```
One is a present-long-monosyllabic word
```

> Not sure. I think Canadians pronounce "squirrel" with only one syllable?

```
One won an imaginary trophy, I've heard
```

> Hmm. In *Alice's Adventures in Wonderland* the Mouse is (I think) one of the participants in the Caucus-Race in which *everyone* wins, but we have at least two candidate mice above already.

```
So now, to complete the entire quiz
Can anyone tell me what this family is?
```

> I still think they're the rodents, even though I am failing to make sense of some of the clues above.

Comment: Nice. I was thinking along the same lines, and managed to solve a couple that you didn't; I think between us we've got everything except possibly the "present-long-monosyllabic word".